# Understanding a proof that $|G|=pq,(p<q) \Rightarrow G$ is not simple.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation, sylow-theory, simple-groups

**Proposition**

Let $G$ be a finite group and $|G|=pq$ where $p<q$ and $p,q$ are prime. Then, $G$ is not simple.

The questioneer of this page [A finite group of order $pq$ cannot be simple.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177431/a-finite-group-of-order-pq-cannot-be-simple) writes the proof of this proposition, but I wonder if that is correct.

Here is the overview of the proof.

By third sylow's theorem, $|\mathrm{syl}_p(G)|$ devides $q$. Since $q>p$ is prome, $|\mathrm{syl}_p(G)|=1.$ Let $P$ be the sylow-$p$ subgroup. Since $1<|P|<|G|$, $P$ is nontrivial subgroup of $G$. By the second sylow's theorem, $g^{-1} P g=P$ for all $g\in G$. Thus, $P$ is nontrivial and normal subgroup of $G$ and $G$ isn't simple.

In the last part, this proof says "By the second sylow's theorem, $g^{-1} P g=P$ for all $g$."

But the second sylow's theorem says that if $H$ and $K$ are $\mathrm{sylow-}p$ subgroups, then there **exists** $g\in G$ s.t. $g^{-1}Hg=K$.

Why can the proof  say "**all** $g\in G$" ?

Comment: The argument should be different: Every $g^{-1}Pg$ is a Sylow $p$-group. How many are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists only one $p$-Sylow subgroup,since the cardinal of $gPg^{-1}$ is $p$, it is a Sylow $p$-group and equal to $P$ since there exists only one group whose cardinal is $p$.

Answer (score 0):

I think Sylow is overkill here. A subgroup of order $q$ (Cauchy) is unique, and hence normal. In fact, if there are more, say $H$ and $K$ two of them. Then $HK$ has size $q^2>pq$, as $H$ and $K$ trivially intersect. But this is a contradiction, because $HK\subseteq G$.

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy's theorem, $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $q$. The index of this subgroup is $[G:H]=p$.

A subgroup of index the smallest prime divisor is normal. Thus, G is not simple.